# Find all occurrences of a word in .txt files with GIT Bash on Windows

Tags: bash, grep, git-bash

Trying to find all occurrences of a word in a range of different .txt files in a directory.
I'm looking for commands that will give me an exact count if possible.

so far I have tried:

```
$ grep -w 'string' *
```

and:

```
$ grep --include=\*.{txt} -rnw desktop/testfiles/ -e "string"
```

The first outputs its entire contents and the second doesn't seem to do anything.
Any ideas?

Comment: does `grep --include='*.txt' -rnw 'string' desktop/testfiles/` work?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Seems to return nothing as did my last grep command.

Comment: What if you use `grep -w "string" *`? If you need to get the count of words, you probably need `grep -oP "\bstring\b" file | wc -l`

Comment: Sorry grep --include='*.txt' -rnw 'string' desktop/testfiles/ had the same result as the first instance. It printed other text in the file.

Comment: it is a bit difficult to understand what you mean by `printed other text` etc.. could you edit your question and add 3-5 lines of the output you get and let us know what is wrong with them? do they not have `string` in them or what?

Comment: @3.14THON what is the problem of my solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply :

```
grep -w "string" *.txt | wc -l
```

also GNU awk allows it to be done in single command

```
awk -v w="string" '$1==w{n++} END{print n}' RS=' |\n' *.txt
```

Comment: Solved it thank you. First attempt only shows a count for each line the string occurs in, not the total count. Second solves it.

Comment: for the first case, since you are not using `-o` option, you can use `grep -cw 'string' *.txt`... to count all matches, not just lines with matches, use `grep -ow 'string' *.txt | wc -l`

Comment: Of course. Thanks again